# Checkboxes and JQuery behaving strangely in Opera and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, checkbox

The sample code uses JQuery to prevent the user from unchecking the last checked checkbox. It works as expected in Firefox and Chrome, but not in Opera or IE.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        #checkboxContainer label {
            float: left;
            clear: right;
        }
        #checkboxContainer input {
            float: left;
            clear: left;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#checkboxContainer input[type='checkbox']").change(function(evt) {
                if ($("#checkboxContainer input[type='checkbox']:checked").length == 0) {
                    console.log("Only 1 checkbox; can't uncheck.");
                    $(evt.target).attr("checked", "checked");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="checkboxContainer">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" checked="checked"/>
        <label for="checkbox1">1</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2"/>
        <label for="checkbox2">2</label>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work in IE and Opera if you change your selector to ":checkbox" instead of "input[type='checkbox']".  The jQuery docs state that the two are equivalent, so I am not sure how to explain the difference in behavior.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#checkboxContainer :checkbox").change(function(evt) {
            if ($("#checkboxContainer :checkbox:checked").length == 0) {
                console.log("Only 1 checkbox; can't uncheck.");
                $(evt.target).attr("checked", "checked");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Matt, this seems to work but I am more interested in the explanation than the workaround.

Comment: An interesting note... I added a div and started writing the count into it, just for debug purposes, and adding that caused your original selectors to work.  Then I removed the reference to the count and just set some static text into a div on the line before the 'if' in my code above: $('#debugDiv').text('static test'), and it also fixed the issue.  Still not an explanation - seems like maybe the DOM needs to change in order for the count to be calculated correctly with that selector.

Comment: Thanks a ton for looking into this further... it may be a JQuery bug. I am completely confused because this is a VERY basic feature.

Answer (score 0):

You Can this No error :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        #checkboxContainer label {
            float: left;
            clear: right;
        }
        #checkboxContainer input {
            float: left;
            clear: left;
        }
    </style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".ceks").click(function() {
                if( !$(".ceks:checked").length ){
                    $(this).attr("checked", "checked");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="checkboxContainer">
        <input type="checkbox" class="ceks" checked="checked"/>
        <label for="checkbox1">1</label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="ceks"/>
        <label for="checkbox2">2</label>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yea. Seems like it has problems with $(".checkboxContainer input[type='checkbox']:checked"), but input:checkbox:checked works.